# Почему интерпретатор не видит функцию?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пытаюсь сделать хендлер для бана пользователей, которые пишут определенные слова.
Проблема в том, что при использовании рекомендуемой функции:
`await bot.kick_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)`
почему в коде навожусь на `kick_chat_member` и мне выдает такое

```
(Cannot find reference 'kick_chat_member' in 'bot.py')
```

Вот код:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import sys

from aiogram.client import bot

from wordBase import ban_words
from os import getenv
from routertry import route
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, Router, types
from aiogram.enums import ParseMode
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.utils.markdown import hbold

TOKEN = "*"

dp = Dispatcher()
dp.include_router(route.router)


@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def command_start_handler(message: Message) -> None:
    await message.answer(f"Hello, {hbold(message.from_user.full_name)}!")

# ПРОБЛЕМА ТУТ !!! 
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.TEXT)
async def handle_message(message: types.Message):
    # Проверяем, содержит ли сообщение запрещенные слова
    banned_words = ["слово1", "слово2", "слово3"]  # Список запрещенных слов
    if any(word in message.text.lower() for word in banned_words):
        # Получаем информацию о чате
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        # Забанить пользователя
        await bot.kick_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)


async def main() -> None:
    bot = Bot(TOKEN, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Версии:
*aiogram 3.2.0* *python 3.11.6*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте доступ к bot из объекта message
await message.bot.ban_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)

Comment: Постарайтесь оставлять немного более развернутые ответы. Исправить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: вот это работает, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
await update.chat_member.chat.ban_member(chat_id, user_id)
```

Дело в том, что этот метод не используется в библиотеке версии 20+

> Удалены устаревшие методыick_chat_member,ickChatMember, get_chat_members_count и getChatMembersCount.

Comment: то же самое, не видит Cannot find reference 'chat_member' in 'update.py'

Comment: Возможно вы не импортировали: from telegram import Update, Chat, ChatMember, ParseMode, ChatMemberUpdated